# Django show a message until user takes an action upon the message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-messages

I would like to display a dashboard notification in the view until user prefers to close it. It should stay there every time the user logs in. But if he clicks the `close`  button on the notification, then the notification shouldn't be shown thereafter.

How to implement this in django using `messages`? Is there any other way?

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications